# Running a python program from a C++ program?

Tags: python, c++, terminal

I've been messing around with Selenium in python, and I really want to have an existing C++ program run my python code.

Basically, my python code just finds a website, and downloads the file which afterwards my C++ program wants to open the file and do a bunch of operations on it. If I had a myPythonCode.py file, and my other C++ files (header.h, main.cpp, otherFunctions.cpp...) how would I go about running the python code from my C++ program?

Also both of my programs are console programs, and I was hoping that a user would have an uninterrupted experience running the program (for example, if the user wants to download a file while running the C++ program the terminal doesn't have to close, or open a different window to start the python program). Any help in going about this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On which operating system? BTW, I feel that your question is off-topic on stackoverflow (since you don't show any source code)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm operating on Windows 7, and I've had a couple of friends tell me to look into std::system for C++ to basically have my C++ program run the python code, and once completed, give control back to my C++ program (although my friend only used C#, he told me that C++ shouldn't be too far off). Also I wasn't sure what source code to include! My code works (whether or not it's bug proof is another matter :P) but I have always come to stackoverflow for help from those much more talented than me.

Comment: If you are a student, learning and using Linux and looking inside free software will teach you a lot.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yea my schoolwork tends to be done on Ubuntu, however this program I'm tinkering around with is basically something that I had been working on since I was a tiny child and had only recently gotten back into. Most of my studies until now haven't been software based, so I figured it would be a good time to start brushing up on my programming...

Answer (score 0):

It is operating system specific, and the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard does not define any functions for that (except [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), which is in C99, and [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) in C++11). On Linux (and other [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems), read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and consider using `system`, or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), or more probably the lower-level [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) like [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), etc etc.... You may want some [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and you may need to have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

You could use some C++ frameworks like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) (both have a process abstraction and are usable on several operating systems, even on proprietary ones from Microsoft)

If you want your C++ program to have a terminal interface on Linux, consider [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) and/or [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)

BTW, several C or C++ libraries for [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) exist, e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for HTTP client side, and [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) for HTTP server side. So you might avoid your Python program and incorporate the downloading in your C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the boost library which allows running python on C++ and using your C++ in python.  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/